# Different result for array first derivative using differences in Fortran and Python

Tags: fortran, derivative

I used function [deriv4()](https://ww2.odu.edu/%7Eagodunov/computing/programs/book2/Ch02/deriv_dd.f90) to calculate the first-order derivative of the following arrays:

```
   xi = (/ 1., 2., 3./)
   yi = (/ -2.457771560159039804e-38, -2.894514456792069804e-39, -1.221311883139507993e-35 /)
```

However, when I compare the results with the numpy.gradient()of Python, they are very different! How can I fix it?

The code (drive.f90) is attached below and compiled as follows:

ifort -o deriv.x drive.f90

```
    program div
    implicit none
    integer, parameter :: ni=3    ! initial arrays size for interpolation
    integer, parameter :: nc=3    ! number of points where derivatives to be calc.
    Integer, Parameter :: SP = Selected_Real_Kind (P=6,R=35)
    Integer, Parameter :: DP = Selected_Real_Kind (P=15,R=300)
    real(kind=DP) xmin, xmax  ! interval
    real(kind=DP) xi(ni), yi(ni)
    real(kind=DP) x, yx,  step, f, deriv3,deriv4
    real(kind=DP) fx ,l,fx2
    integer i, j
    
       xi = (/ 1., 2., 3./)
       yi = (/ -2.457771560159039804e-38_DP, -2.894514456792069804e-39_DP, -1.221311883139507993e-35_DP /)
    
    l=0 
    do i=1, NC
      l=l+1.0
      fx = deriv3(xi(i), xi, yi, nc, 1)
       write (*,*) xi(i), yi(i), fx!,fx2
    end do
    stop
 end program
    
      function deriv3(xx, xi, yi, ni, m)
    !====================================================================
    ! Evaluate first- or second-order derivatives 
    ! using three-point Lagrange interpolation 
    ! written by: Alex Godunov (October 2009)
    !--------------------------------------------------------------------
    ! input ...
    ! xx    - the abscissa at which the interpolation is to be evaluated
    ! xi()  - the arrays of data abscissas
    ! yi()  - the arrays of data ordinates
    ! ni - size of the arrays xi() and yi()
    ! m  - order of a derivative (1 or 2)
    ! output ...
    ! deriv3  - interpolated value
    !============================================================================*/
    
    implicit none
    Integer, Parameter :: SP = Selected_Real_Kind (P=6,R=35)
    
    Integer, Parameter :: DP = Selected_Real_Kind (P=15,R=300)
    integer, parameter :: n=3
    real(kind=DP) deriv3, xx
    integer ni, m
    real(kind=DP) xi(ni), yi(ni)
    real(kind=DP) x(n), f(n)
    integer i, j, k, ix
    
    ! exit if too high-order derivative was needed,
    if (m > 2) then
      deriv3 = 0.0
      return
    end if
    
    ! if x is ouside the xi(1)-xi(ni) interval set deriv3=0.0
    if (xx < xi(1) .or. xx > xi(ni)) then
      deriv3 = 0.0
      return
    end if
    
    ! a binary (bisectional) search to find i so that xi(i-1) < x < xi(i)
    i = 1
    j = ni
    do while (j > i+1)
      k = (i+j)/2
      if (xx < xi(k)) then
        j = k
      else
        i = k
      end if
    end do
    
    ! shift i that will correspond to n-th order of interpolation
    ! the search point will be in the middle in x_i, x_i+1, x_i+2 ...
      i = i + 1 - n/2
    
    ! check boundaries: if i is ouside of the range [1, ... n] -> shift i
    if (i < 1) i=1
    if (i + n > ni) i=ni-n+1
    
    !  old output to test i
    !  write(*,100) xx, i
    !  100 format (f10.5, I5)
    
    ! just wanted to use index i
    ix = i
    
    ! initialization of f(n) and x(n)
    do i=1,n
      f(i) = yi(ix+i-1)
      x(i) = xi(ix+i-1)
    end do
    
    ! calculate the first-order derivative using Lagrange interpolation
    if (m == 1) then
        deriv3 =          (2.0*xx - (x(2)+x(3)))*f(1)/((x(1)-x(2))*(x(1)-x(3)))
        deriv3 = deriv3 + (2.0*xx - (x(1)+x(3)))*f(2)/((x(2)-x(1))*(x(2)-x(3)))
        deriv3 = deriv3 + (2.0*xx - (x(1)+x(2)))*f(3)/((x(3)-x(1))*(x(3)-x(2)))
    ! calculate the second-order derivative using Lagrange interpolation
      else
        deriv3 =          2.0*f(1)/((x(1)-x(2))*(x(1)-x(3)))
        deriv3 = deriv3 + 2.0*f(2)/((x(2)-x(1))*(x(2)-x(3)))
        deriv3 = deriv3 + 2.0*f(3)/((x(3)-x(1))*(x(3)-x(2)))
    end if
    end function deriv3
```

The output of drive.f90 is as follows:

```
       xi                          yi                derivative
   1.00000000000000      -2.457771560159040E-038  6.137636960186341E-036
   2.00000000000000      -2.894514456792070E-039 -6.094270557896745E-036
   3.00000000000000      -1.221311883139508E-035 -1.832617807597983E-035
```

The output of Python is as follows:

```
import numpy as np
f = np.array([-2.457771560159039804e-38, -2.894514456792069804e-39, -1.221311883139507993e-35 ], dtype=float)
print(np.gradient(f))
```

Compare outputs

**Nupmy of python:**

```
[ 2.16832011e-38 -6.09427056e-36 -1.22102243e-35]
```

**Fortran drive.f90 code:**

6.137636960186341E-036, -6.094270557896745E-036, -1.832617807597983E-035

Comment: Please put the code in the question - don't ask us to follow links to lord knows where. Please also tell us what answers you expect (I don't do python personally) and how you compiled the Fortran, and make sure you provide a full program so we can run the same tests as you.

Comment: Be aware that there is no single correct derivative of an array. Derivatives are for smooth functions. You can compute finite difference approximations of a derivative. There are various approximations of various order of accuracy. There can be multiple alternative difference schemes for a particular order. I suggest askimg at https://scicomp.stackexchange.com if you are into the numerical analysis part and not just Fortran programming.

Comment: I suggest to try comparing your programs with some more reasonable values and not such small numbers as 1e-36. These schemes are very simple and you should be able to easily check the results even just with a pen and paper. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_method and https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference_coefficient

Comment: In particular, check whether the same one-sided approximation schemes are used for the Fortran and the Python code. There are several possible choices that can be made. There is no universal true answer. Try a larger array so that you have points that are farher from the boundaries. And definitely try simpler numbers, not 1e-36.

Comment: I have to work on a lot of types of numbers (~1e-36). For example, I put three numbers in this code.

Comment: I am *amazed* these numbers are so similar given the unreasonable values of y1 you are supplying. To be absolutely sure there are any real differences you will have to do some numerical analysis, but I am 95% sure that in floating point maths these are the same numbers. If these are typical values of y1 I strongly suggest rescaling the variables in our problem to get something nearer to unity

Comment: That said I would change the constants in the Fortran to be of the correct kind. I doubt it will make a difference as they are all exactly representable in "double precision", but better safe than sorry.

Comment: @shylm And I am saying that you should check those algotithms and subroutines 1. with simpler numbers, 2. with larger arrays. Only later proceed to the numbers you have. In that step consider same scaling as Ian already suggested.

Answer (score 1):

There is a fundamental difference between the two cases in the edge cases. The OP demonstrates that the derivatives for the central case are both computed by numpy and `deriv3` are identical. The other values are not.

**`numpy.gradent`:** This method uses second-order accurate central differences in the interior points and either first or second-order accurate one-sided (forward or backwards) differences at the boundaries (See [Documentation numpy.gradient](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.gradient.html) ). In the default calling-convention, this implies that the produced values are:

```
[ f[1] - f[0], (f[2] - f[0]) * 0.5, f[2] - f[1] ]
```

**deriv3:** This method uses a polynomial interpolation method to compute the derivatives. The method constructs a polynomial on the three neighbouring points and computes the derivative of the respective polynomial. The Lagrange three-point interpolation formula is given by:

```
f(x1+p*h) = 0.5*p*(p-1)*f(x0) + (1-p^2)*f(x1) + 0.5*p*(p+1)*f(x2)
```

and its derivative to `p` is given by:

```
f'(x1+p*h) = (p-0.5)*f(x0) - 2*p*f(x1) + (p+0.5)*f(x2)
```

For the OP, this gives the following array:

```
[ 2*f[1] - 1.5*f[0] -0.5*f[2], (f[2] - f[0])*0.5, 1.5*f[2] - 2*f[1] + 0.5*f[1] ]
```

As you notice, both methods are different at the edge-cases.

There are a plethora of methods to compute derivatives of a discrete set of points, all with its pros and cons. An old, but very nice reference of different methods can be found in [Abramowitz and Stegun](http://www.nrbook.com/abramowitz_and_stegun_html/page_877.htm)

Comment: This is exactly why I urged the OP to test a larger array and to check which one-sided approximations are used. To have points that are not influenced by the boundaries and to see what differences are made there.